# .bat поиск и удаление

Tags: bat

В рашареной папке нужно удалить у каждого пользователя папку "Шаблоны" в ней скапливаются файлы которые сильно загружает сервер

\file\file\%username%\appdata\romaning\microsoft\Шаблоны

как мне это реализовать одним скриптом или батником не прибегая к "планировщику задач"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd \file\file
for /d %d in (*.*) do (
    cd "%d\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft" && rd /s /q "Шаблоны" && md "Шаблоны" 
    cd \file\file
)
```

Answer (score 0):

как то так

```
RD /S /Q "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Шаблоны"
```

Comment: так удалит только в одной директории

Comment: у каждого юзера, я знаю
немного не до читал вопрос